# Can't create a new MySQL database in for Wordpress blog in Microsoft Azure

Tags: mysql, wordpress, azure

Yesterday I created a Wordpress blog in Microsoft Azure (I have a DreamSpark Student account subscription) without any problem. Upon creating the blog, Azure also created a DefaultMySQL DB for me to use.

Today though, because I didn't like the url I gave my Wordpress blog, I deleted it, an tried to create another. But now, everytime I try to create a new WordPress site, I can't select DefaultMySQL DB as my database. I tried to create another DB (Mercury-Free DB) , but for some it doesn't work (the new database I tried to create is not listed in my resources, and wordpress doesn't accept it as a valid DB)

Anyone had this problem before?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a credit card associated with your account? The MySQL databases use ClearDB an external database provider which requires a credit card.

Comment: DreamSpark accounts are for students do not require a credit card association.
At any rate, I'm fine with only having a DefaultSQL DB like I do now, the problem is that I can't use it to create a new wordpress site, and I don't know why.

Comment: If you want to create the Wordpress site, you're going to need to still associate a credit card because of ClearDB (even on Dreamspark). See: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fac29bfe-a7a6-4132-8039-79a87362122d/azure-database-error-while-creating-it-from-dreamspark-subscription